# SQLAlchemy For a Read-only Query, what to use: session.expire() vs session.commit()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am quite confused with the need for `session.commit()` during an `SQLAlchemy` query to avoid stale data, in situations where I fetch/read **only** data from the Database.

There is also a `session.expire()` option, which is apparently called after a `session.commit()` {given that expire_on_commit=True, which it is by default}.

If I only fetch data from the Database, is it necessary to use `session.commit()`? Or `session.expire()` alone will suffice?

In our current setup, `session.commit()` does the job. Will replacing it with `session.expire()` keep the solution?

It takes days to test if the data becomes stale.
We do not own the Database and we should not be changing anything there. I'm afraid `session.commit()` can accidentally push changes into the Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expiring the session prompts a fetch from the database the next time you try to access loaded data. Since you do not wish to push any changes to the database, I see no reason why this would not suffice.

Note that [session.expire_all()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=expire#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expire_all) is called after `session.commit()`, so I would recommend replacing `session.commit()` with `session.expire_all()` or be careful to call `session.expire()` on all the instances you wish to refresh.

Comment: I see. So I can use a single `session.expire_all()` in a main control function or multiple `session.expire()` declared in each instance of db query